# Navigation Menu on Wordpress Page Items

Tags: wordpress

I have a word press navigation bar which has 2 buttons Home and Contact. When hovering on the contact page there is a sub item called number. How do I stop the user navigating to the parent link? and only allow them to selected number and navigate to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way would be to create that parent menu item with a URL of `#/` which will prevent the click.  It will append `#/` to the url in the browser, but other than that nothing else will happen.  Note that the slash at the end will prevent the page from scrolling to the top when clicked which is especially useful if you have a sticky menu.

If you want to prevent the URL from changing in your browser you can add some Javascript to prevent the click event for links with a href of `#/` like this bit of jQuery...

```
$('a[href*=\\#\\/]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As Jaxon said in the comments, you could then use CSS to [change the cursor](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/) on those parent items (to `default` perhaps).

If you felt this method was too "hacky" you could [use a Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) to actually override the output HTML, but depending on your implementation that feels like overkill to me for such a small effect.  Plus, once you strip the `a` tag out you could run into other issues with your menu if your dropdowns require that tag to work properly.

Comment: Agreed, the #/ solution should work, but you will have the on hover styles should a clickable button. You can always do a event.preventDefault() in JS and change the :hover cursor in CSS, but I would consider that an unmaintainable and hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps in the wordpress console.

https://connectnc.com/clients/knowledgebase/112/How-to-make-menu-item-unclickable.html